# Boundary matching \b in regex

Tags: java, regex

I came across this example in the KB book. Can please someone explain it to me? Thanks in advance :)

```
java RegTest "\\b" "w2w w$ &#w2"
```

output:

> match positions: 0 3 4 5 9 11

Comment: Ok.. Without the code for `RegTest` we are *sitting ducks* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind: [Seems to come from here](http://www.apuntesdejava.com/2015/02/conociendo-regex-parte-12.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `RegTest` is meant to list all those positions in the string that match a given regex.

The `\b` regex is a word boundary, one of those zero-width markers like `^` and `$`, that matches things *between* characters (including before and after the entire test string).

The word boundary appears at the start and end of the string if the adjacent character is a word character (`w` or `[A-Za-z0-9_]`), as well as at any point where it transitions from word character to non-word character(`\W` or `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`) in either direction.

So the positions are before the characters marked with `^` below:

```
w2w w$ &#w2
^  ^^^   ^ ^
0  345   9 11
```